# Como declarar una función que me devuelva un objeto json en postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, function

Quiero hacer una función en la que le pase como parámetro el nombre de una tabla, y me devuelva un json.

El cuerpo si lo uso en un query ya me funciona ejemplo:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(u))) FROM cons:ban() u;
```

Esto me devuelve un json, pero lo que quiero es hacer una función en la que le pase como parámetro el nombre de una tabla, y me devuelva el json.

---

Probablemente no me explique bien, lo que necesito saber es como construir la función, para que reciba como parámetro el nombre de una tabla que tipo de dato debo indicarle en el RETURN de la función para que me devuelva el JSON (que ya obtengo con la consulta:
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(u))) FROM cons:ban() u;) esta consulta ya me está devolviendo el JSON, solo necesito que pueda cambiar el nombre de la tabla..

de nuevo muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Pues usar la función EXECUTE para construir tu sentencia en base a tus parametros;
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE inserted_by = $1 AND inserted <= $2'
   INTO c
  USING checked_user, checked_date;
```

Comment: Probablemente no me explique bien, lo que necesito saber es como construir la función, para que reciba como parámetro el nombre de una tabla que tipo de dato debo indicarle en el RETURN de la función para que me devuelva el JSON (que ya obtengo con la consulta: SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(u))) FROM cons:ban() u;) esta consulta ya me está devolviendo el JSON, solo necesito que pueda cambiar el nombre de la tabla..

de nuevo muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Gracias, leí la liga que pusiste y ya quedó

Answer (score 0):

```
drop function if exists myfunction_1;
create function myfunction_1()
returns setof json 
as $$
declare 
    _myvar1 int;
begin
return query select row_to_json(q) 
    from 
        (select col1, col2 from mytable c where col1 = _myvar1) q;
end; 
$$ language plpgsql;
```